# The instance member '' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: java, flutter, dart

[this error appears from line 43 to 48 how can I solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYd4w.png)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: am new here i will try to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that Home screen parameters doesn't accept nullable values,
in order to solve this you have two options

1. remove the "late" word before declaring the variables
2. To make HomeScreen constructer accept the null values like this for
   ex:  String? BMR